# Python 3 - Converting byte string to string with same content

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, python-2.x

I am working on migrating project code from Python 2 to Python 3.
One piece of code is using struct.pack which provides me value in string(Python2) and byte string(Python3)
I wanted to convert byte string in python3 to normal string. Converted string should have same content to make it consistent with existing values.
For e.g.

```
in_val = b'\0x01\0x36\0xff\0x27' # Input value
out_val = '\0x01\0x36\0xff\0x27' # Output should be this
```

I have one solution to convert in_val in string then explicitly remove 'b' and '\' character which will appear after its converted to string.

Is there any other solution to convert using clean way.
Any help appreciated

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Python 2 `str` *is* a byte string. Are you *certain* that the remainder of the code must treat the `struct.unpack` result as text?

Answer (score 0):

`str` values are always *Unicode code points*. The first 256 values are the *Latin-1* range, so you can use that codec to decode bytes directly to those codepoints:

```
out_val = in_val.decode('latin1')
```

However, you want to re-assess why you are doing this. Don't store binary data in strings, there are almost always better ways to deal with binary data. If you want to store binary data in JSON, for example, then you'd want to use Base64 or some other binary-to-text encoding scheme that better handles edge cases such as binary data containing escape codes when interpreted as text.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for your comment. We need to this as we are moving complete project from Python 2 to 3 as already said. Its difficult to change much of the code as it will take very much testing effort. So we are looking for some solution that will perfectly mimic output of Python 2 operation in Python3. I am trying with 'latin-1' encoding.